# angularjs ui-grid changing column height to auto causes weird line to show up on other columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, angular-ui-grid

i have a column that i want to dynamically change the height but once i change the height you can see in the image the other column's height gets adjusted accordingly but their background column is brown now.

i changed the height of this css class 
`.ui-grid-cell{height:auto}`

i want the background of other columns to be complely white, how can this be fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to change the following in `ui-grid.css`

```
   .cellheight .ui-grid-row {
    display: table-row;
    height: auto !important;
}
.cellheight .ui-grid-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    height: auto !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
.cellheight .ui-grid-cell-contents {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't resolve the issue. my issue isn't that i want all rows to be white background. my issue is that weird line that shows up on rows whose height got increased because of other row which had attribute (height:auto)

Comment: @ua_boaz : you should try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648643/angularjs-ui-grid-row-not-resizing-according-to-content
and this - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3239#issuecomment-91045267